# Do isometries preserve lengths of paths?

Tags: differential-geometry

If I have two regular surfaces $S_1, S_2$, with first fundamental forms expressed by two matrices $M_1, M_2$ and an isometry $\phi$ between them, does this mean that the length of a curve $\beta$ on $S_1$ measured according to $M_1$ is the same as that of $\phi\circ\beta$ measured according to $M_2$?

Or the only lengths preserved are the ones of the geodesics?

(in the comments I've posted a little longer explanation of what I'm trying to do)

Comment: If this adds some details: I'm taking $S_1$ = Disk model of Poincaré's hyperbolic plane with 
$M_1 = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{4}{(1-u^2-v^2)^2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{4}{(1-u^2-v^2)^2}
\end{bmatrix}$,
$S_2$ = Half plane model of Poincaré's hyperbolic plane with $M_2 = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{v^2} & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{v^2}
\end{bmatrix}$,
and, identifying $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $\mathbb{C}$, $\beta(t)=t\cdot i $,
$\phi(z)=i\cdot\frac{1-z}{1+z}:\mathbb{C}\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ (therefore $\phi\circ\beta(t)=\frac{2t}{1+t^2}+i\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$)

Comment: The line $\beta$ in $S_1$ from $(0,0)$ to $(0,\frac{1}{2})$ becomes a quarter of a cirlce on $S_2$ from $(0,1)$ to $(\frac{4}{5},\frac{3}{5})$

I'm therefore computing the length of $\beta$ according to $M_1$ and comparing it to the length of $\phi\circ\beta$ computed through $M_2$, expecting to get the same number, but so it is not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, turns out I had made a little mistake in effectively computing $M_2$. Indeed, the answer is YES, as the theory states.
(I don't know if to delete the question, since it may be useful to someone, one day)

Comment: Here some brute code for the computations (I was helped by Wolframalpha):
$\phi\circ\beta ' = { -2(t2-1)/((1+t2)^2) , -4t/((1+t2)^2) }$
$(\phi\circ\beta) ' \cdot M_2 \cdot (\phi\circ\beta) '  = (\phi\circ\beta) '\cdot{{((1+t2)/(1 - t2))^2, 0}, {0, ((1+t2)/(1 - t2))^2}} (\cdot \phi\circ\beta) '$

Comment: So the final integral to compute is
$\sqrt{(16 t^2)/((1 - t^2)^2 (1 + t^2)^2) + (4 (-1 + t^2)^2)/((1 - t^2)^2 (1 + t^2)^2))}$ from 0 to 0.5